# How to dismiss "install packages" message in Android Studio SDK Manager

Tags: android-studio

The SDK Manager dialogue of Android Studio shows packages that I am not interested in installing (see screen capture below).  Is there any way to dismiss this message?

I am using Android Studio 1.0 RC 2 on Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: If you click `Deselect All` then you can choose the packages you want from afresh.

Comment: @Joel Tried several combinations of select all/deselect all, but could not get rid of the five packages!